# Session store in InProc vs Redis (Asp.Net MVC 5) with scalability in mind

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redis, scalability, session-state

I can't decide whether to use InProc or Redis to store user session + a little extra data (username, email... etc) in a high-performance web application

So what are the advantages and disadvantages of both? Because Redis option would have the disadvantage of using HTTP connections -- network latency and consuming TCP connections which HTTP use.

Also, would InProc hold the application future from using multiple IIS workers in place or on different servers (using Load Balancing)

Note: If I would use Redis, I would inject the session state by a custom action attribute to a property in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a web farm scenario, a request can go to any worker process in the web farm. Using the in-proc session state store in such a case can result in data loss if different requests for the same session are served by different worker processes. However, if using just a single web server, the in-proc session state provider should be the fastest as there is no additional network latency.

Redis works as a distributed cache and the Redis session state provider would work well for web farm scenarios as all the various worker processes in the web farm would communicate with the single Redis instance. Physically placing the Redis instance close to the web farm instances can help to reduce latencies to some extent.